Duplicate ID field with empty value
I'm writing logic to register users using a Go backend and a MongoDB database. I want to be able to send the data to the frontend via JSON and to mongo via BSON, so my model looks like this
package database

type User struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID   `json:"_id,omitempty", bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Role      string               `json:"role,omitempty, "bson:"role,omitempty"`
    Name      string               `json:"name,omitempty", bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Email     string               `json:"email,omitempty", bson:"email,omitempty"`
    Favorites []primitive.ObjectID `json:"favorites,omitempty", bson:"favorites,omitempty"`
    Password  []byte               `json:"-", bson:"password,omitempty"`
}

My registration function looks like this
func Register(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    fmt.Println("Registering user.")
    var data map[string]string

    if err := c.BodyParser(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // check if email already used
    var user database.User
    if err := database.Users.FindOne(c.Context(), bson.M{"email": data["email"]}).Decode(&user); err == nil {
        c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest)
        return c.JSON(fiber.Map{
            "message": "Email already in use",
        })
    }

    password, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(data["password"]), 14)

    user = database.User{
        Role:     "viewer",
        Name:     data["name"],
        Email:    data["email"],
        Password: password,
    }

    result, err := database.Users.InsertOne(c.Context(), user)
    fmt.Println("Inserted user to database")

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return c.JSON(result)
}

This mostly works, except the documents in my DB always have a duplicate "id" field (no underscore) that is all 0's.

If I simply remove the JSON configuration so the ID field reads ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`, the issue is avoided, but again, I want the JSON configuration. I could make separate DB and Client models for everything to completely sidestep the issue but I'd rather not add more complexity than is necessary.
So my questions are:

Why is this happening?
Is there a way to do what I want without this issue?


Remove the comma between json and bson tags. The way it is written, it is probably not seeing the bson tags at all.

@BurakSerdar I am extremely annoyed that this was the correct answer

Run go vet. It'll tell you.
